# Is there a way to throw an error for undeclared constants?

Tags: php

We have an intern who wrote

```
$this->method(ct);
```

instead of

```
$this->method('ct');
```

This doesn't throw an error, but I want it to.  How?

I don't like PHP guessing.

Comment: It's not an error in PHP, is it?  It's a logical error caused by the programmer.  Software testing should have caught this.

Comment: Try to enable the error reporting of php : `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on PHP error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` so that all warnings and errors are reported.  From there, you can make your own error handling method to catch these warnings/errors and do with them what you want instead of them just being piped out to the output.  A good example of an error handling method is right here http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.examples.php

Cheers.

EDIT: In fact, a custom error handling method will handle all errors whether they are being reported or not, so the `error_reporting` line would be superfluous. Check out that link.

Answer (score 1):

It is documented behaviour that PHP treats an undefined constant as a string constant with the name of the constant as a value. So this code actually works!

It issues a warning, though, but that warning may be ignored. You can call [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to set which kinds of errors are outputted. `error_reporting` can also be set in php.ini.

I assume you have a development environment that is separate from your production environment. If so, I'd set those reporting on the highest level for your development and testing environments, and set it slightly lower for your production environment. When developing, you want to be confronted by those messages, but in production you want to maybe log them, but not show them to the user.

Also take a look at the [`display_errors` directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

Answer (score 0):

in your method do testing if argument is string

```
function method($arg){
   if (!is_string($arg)){
      throw new exception("argument must be a string. ".get_type($arg)." given");
   }
}
```